# Polymer Call Back giving the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: angular, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to create a callback for a key press in a polymer paper-listbox in my angular dart component. The callback seems to be set up. The key is pageup. If I press it when focus is outside the listbox, nothing happens. Inside the listbox, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
  Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior._triggerKeyHandler @ (index):14940
  Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior._onKeyBindingEvent @ (index):14924
```

The pertinent code in my component is:

```
@Component(selector: 'my-artists',
templateUrl: 'artists_component.html',
//encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,  // added for polymer
styleUrls: const['artist.css']
)

class ArtistsComponent implements OnInit {
  PaperListbox listbox;
...
void ngOnInit() {
  getArtists();
  listbox = querySelector('.scroll-list');
  listbox.addOwnKeyBinding('pageup', 'onPageUp');
}
...
void onPageUp(Event e) {
  print('in page up');
}
```

The html is:

```
<paper-listbox class="scroll-list">
  <paper-item class="item-height" *ngFor="let artist of artists" [class.selected]="artist == selectedArtist" (click)="onSelect(artist)">
      {{artist.first_name}} {{artist.last_name}}
  </paper-item>
</paper-listbox>
```

The index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Jazz Cat</title>
  <script>
    window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
    window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
  </script>

  <!-- For testing using pub serve directly use: -->
  <base href="/">
  <!-- For testing in WebStorm use: -->
  <!-- <base href="/dart/web/"> -->

<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_header_panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_item.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/paper_menu_button.html">
<link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style is="custom-style">
...
</style>
<script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</html>
```

The error appears to be commonplace as there are several questions mentioning it on stackoverflow. None seem to fit my situation. I also saw a bug report from two years back that I would have thought had been fixed by now.
I'm using:

```
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.17
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.17
```

I'm testing in Dartium. This is the line of code in Polymer.IronAllKeysBehavior._onKeyBindingEvent:

```
this[handlerName].call(this, event);
```

handlerName is "onPageUp". this is a paper-listbox.scroll-list object. event is a CustomEvent for the pageup key.

Comment: Is this only in Dartium or also in Chrome?

Comment: Only in Dartium at the moment. When I tried it in Chrome, I got a strange error, which I'll document in the question.

Comment: Did you enable shadow DOM?

Comment: I presume you mean in Chrome. I've tried to follow some web instructions, but can't find it. I can bring up dev tools and go to settings. I don't see it there.

Comment: See https://dart.academy/dart-angular-2-and-polymer-together/ "Step 3: Index"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+paper-listbox+user%3Ame

Comment: I used the tutorial as the basis for my client so I do have index set up that way. I'll add it to my question. The strange thing is that an almost identical call in another component works fine.

Comment: I copied the code to the working component and got the same error as I do in Dartium.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: I'd report a bug in the polymer_elements GitHub repo.